# How do you insert a vertical column of text in Sublime Text 2 using the vim key bindings?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

How do you insert a vertical column of text and indent it in Sublime Text 2 using the vim key bindings?

[image: Vertical Text Selection in Vim]
<sub>(source: [yannesposito.com](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/img/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/rectangular-blocks.gif))</sub>

I have seen the [Sublime Text 2 Column Selection Docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html), showing how you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>, but is it possible to do the same thing using the vim shortcut?

I am using [Sublime in Vintage Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html).

Comment: Do you mean "typing `<C-v>jjjI-- <Esc>` in ST2 Vintage mode"? Well, if you tried it and it doesn't working then the answer is no. IIRC, you can easily find the file containing the commands that make up "vintage mode" in ST2's directory and look around if something ressembling `<C-v>` is there.

Comment: I've just dowloaded a fresh dev nightly and I couldn't find anything pertaining to visual-block mode in `vintage.package`. Column editing is still available with `<Shift><Alt>+arrows` (on Linux) but you can't use `<C-v>` like in Vim: it still does the standard "paste". i think that the answer to your question is "No.", but ST2 is progressing quickly and steadily so the situation may change a lot in the future.

Comment: Also I want to know how to cut the contents selected by ctrl+alt+arrows (on windows). In vim, I just <Ctrl-v> and select the contents and x.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit fiddly and an extra keystroke, but it is possible: you just have to split the selection into multiple cursors before you do the standard VIM <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

So the whole routine (on a Mac) is:

1. Select block with <kbd>V/v</kbd> + motion keys
2. <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
3. <kbd>V/v</kbd> to exit visual mode
4. Multiple cursors that you can move, insert, whatever!

---

**Alternatively,** you can do what I did and adopt a hybrid approach by changing Sublime's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + arrow keybindings to be <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + motion keys instead.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+k"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} }
]
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> conflicts with OS X's built-in "kill all lines" binding, but ST bindings override those, and you shouldn't be using that one anyway... it's from Emacs ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mouse you can click and drag with with middle mouse button to do a visual block, I've never found a keyboard command for visual block in ST2 Vintage Mode though.