# Sublime text copy paste individual lines

Tags: web, text, copy

Say for example you had the lines:

```
Object1 
Object2 
Object3
```

but then you wanted to duplicate each line right next to it on the SAME line as follows:

```
Object1 Object1 
Object2 Object2 
Object3 Object3
```

But you had thousands of lines that you just wanted to copy over. Obviously it'd be time consuming having to go to each line and then copying individually. Is there a way to do this using sublime text? Basically I have thousands of objects and each object has a property with a name of the object of itself, so I would like to do some easy pasting with sublime, if that is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you insert a vertical column of text in Sublime Text 2 using the vim key bindings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727561/how-do-you-insert-a-vertical-column-of-text-in-sublime-text-2-using-the-vim-key)

Comment: your file (containing lines) is a text file ?

Comment: Dup mentions ST2, but column selection works for ST3 as well.

Comment: @shoover Well that one doesn't really explain how you uniquely copy. You can copy the same thing to multiple lines, but what I am asking is how you copy each single line and then paste on to that very line. Like copying each row and getting multiple cursors doesn't really help because I can only add the same thing to multiple lines. Adding "Hey how's it going" can be done with regular multi-cursor. But how do you get each row to copy itself, and paste right next to itself.

Comment: Does the text that you need to copy have the same number of characters in each row? Like in your example, Object1, Object2, Object3 all have 7 characters (8 with space). If so, then you can use column selection, which was the point of the other question. You select columns 1-8 of however many rows you need, then copy, then move the cursor to where you want to put the copy, and then paste.

Comment: Ok thanks. Someone answered it on the forums:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unique-individual-copy-column-paste-feature/20985/2